# How to insert one dictionary into another dictionary when it is a list in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have one dictionary under a list and i want to insert another dictionary into that list. So need help in Python.

```
custom_fields = {
    "183": issue['Sprint#'],
    "7": issue['AffectedVersion'],
    "11": issue['Severity'],
    "13": issue['Tag'],
    "180": issue['Tester root cause'],
    "93": issue['Testcase ID'],
    "150": issue['Subsystem']
}
custom_field_payload = {'custom_value_fields':custom_fields.items()}
payload = {'issue' : dict(payload.items()+default_payload.items())}
```

Inside the issue, i want custom_field_payload. Please help me to resolve.

**Expected output:**

```
{"issue": {
    "custom_field_values": {
        "183" : "Sprint-1",
        "7" : "12.5.0",
        "11" : "Low (P4)",
        "13" : "Functional",
        "180" : "Legacy Issue identified in Sprint",
        "93" : "CERT-20083926:FN_Update_Gemalto_HSMSettings_Available_Status_DefaultOptionEnabled_ChangeInvalidPassword",
        "150" : "CERTIFICATE"
    },
    "project_id" : 25,
    "category_id": 2380
}}
```

Comment: Expected Output:

Comment: { "issue": {
        "custom_field_values": {
            "183": "Sprint-1",
            "7":"12.5.0",
            "11":"Low (P4)",
            "13":"Functional",
            "180":"Legacy Issue identified in Sprint",
            "93":"CERT-20083926:FN_Update_Gemalto_HSMSettings_Available_Status_DefaultOptionEnabled_ChangeInvalidPassword",
            "150":"CERTIFICATE"
        },
        "project_id": 25,
        "category_id": 2380}}

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Provide traceback and more detailed task description, please

Answer (score 0):

Try the below, simply add list to `items` stuff:

```
custom_field_payload = {'custom_value_fields':custom_fields.items()}
payload = {'issue' : dict(list(payload.items())+list(custom_field_payload.items()))}
```

Comment: other than custom_field_payload, i have additional payload also payload = {
  "subject": issue['Subject'],
  "fixed_version_id" : fixed_version_id,
  "assigned_to_id" : assignee[issue['Assignee']],
  "parent_issue_id" : int(issue['ParentTask']),
  "tracker_id" : trackers[issue['Tracker']],
  "priority_id" : priorities[issue['Priority']],
  "description": issue['Description'],
 }

Comment: @AravindArun Edited mine.

Comment: getting error unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'list'

Comment: payload is a dictionary

Comment: @AravindArun Try now

Comment: now getting this error dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 19; 2 is required

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
issue = {'Sprint#': "Sprint-1",
         'AffectedVersion': "12.5.0",
         'Severity': "Low (P4)",
         'Tag': "Functional",
         'Tester root cause': "Legacy Issue identified in Sprint",
         'Testcase ID': "CERT-20083926:FN_Update_Gemalto_HSMSettings_Available_Status_DefaultOptionEnabled_ChangeInvalidPassword",
         'Subsystem': "CERTIFICATE"}

default_payload = {"project_id": 25, "category_id": 2380}
custom_fields = {
    "183": issue['Sprint#'],
    "7": issue['AffectedVersion'],
    "11": issue['Severity'],
    "13": issue['Tag'],
    "180": issue['Tester root cause'],
    "93": issue['Testcase ID'],
    "150": issue['Subsystem']
}
custom_field_payload = {'custom_field_values':custom_fields}
p = {'issue' : custom_field_payload}
payload = default_payload.copy()
payload.update(p)

print(payload)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the error you're experiencing goes as follows: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict_items' and 'dict_items'`. Let's interpret this error.

`TypeError` -> first-off, we can see that this is a `TypeError`, that means that we've made an error with which type(s) we're using.

`unsupported operand type(s) for +:` -> this is telling us that we've tried to add two operands, but their type was unsupported (invalid).

`'dict_items' and 'dict_items'` -> finally, this tells us that we've tried to add two `dict_items`, which is the method `items` inside of `dict` class (`dict.items`).

Now we know that the error was gotten because we tried to add two `dict.items` which isn't supported, so we can't proceed to add those two.

What I think you tried to do is insert `default_payload` to the `payload` dictionary. In order to do that, you can replace your `payload` dictionary with this:

```
payload = {'issue': custom_field}
payload.update(default_payload)
```

The `dict.update` method inserts a dictionary into another dictionary.